# email template pug file absolutely path for pug file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, nodemailer, email-templates

when i send the mail using email template via node-mailer 
i want to call the template path like /emails/booked/html.pug

```
const email = new Email({
transport: transporter,
send: true,
preview: false,
});
try{
email.send({
template: `booked`, 
message: {
from: 'f@gmail.com',
to: '123@.gmail.com',
subject: 'booed ticket',
text: " "
},
});
} catch(error){console.log("got error while sending email ===========>>>", error)}
```

current directory structure is like :

```
 =>config
 =>controllers=>play.js
 =>emails => template_name => html.pug
 =>logs
 =>routes
 =>main.js
```

I want to call a variable here 
containing the path to the template which can be stored on the 
server or aws path can be like : /emails/booked/html.pug

Comment: What is your entire directory structure? Where is this being called from?

Comment: Hi Rastalamm, please check the updated post, I have added the structure.